# what is disabled decorator in python?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

While I'm reading some python code, I saw the following:

```
@disabled
class IterCases(BaseMatchCase):
```

which is hard to find the meaning of 'disabled' decorator. It looks like 'not' disabling the class itself, since it is actively used at run time.

Comment: Look for an import at the top; this is **not** a standard library decorator but a third party library. In other words, **we'll have to guess** and guessing blind at that.

Comment: Look for a function called `disabled`, it is probably coming from a module you have imported.

Answer (score 3):

I found the [exact source code](https://github.com/floodlight/oftest/blob/master/tests/pktact.py) you appear to be looking at.

That decorator is defined in the [`oftest.testutils` module](https://github.com/floodlight/oftest/blob/master/src/python/oftest/testutils.py) as:

```
def disabled(cls):
    """
    Testcase decorator that marks the test as being disabled.
    These tests are not automatically added to the "standard" group or
    their module's group.
    """
    cls._disabled = True
    return cls
```

so all it does is set a `_disabled` attribute. I found a [`load_test_modules()` function](https://github.com/floodlight/oftest/blob/e53294aeaa71ff5afedb3f24b1bfa46e5a41632d/oft#L248) that then uses this attribute to skip any class that has `_disabled` set to `True`.

At a glance, the decorator appears to be used for any *base* classes; classes used by the actual test case classes.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but when is this decorator function (disabled) called? When I create an instance?

Comment: It is applied when the class definition is run; so when the module is imported in this case.